# Python Application does nothing

Tags: python, null

This code stopped doing anything at all after I changed something that I no longer remember

```
#Dash Shell
import os
import datetime

class LocalComputer:
    pass

def InitInformation():
    Home = LocalComputer()
    #Acquires user information
    if (os.name == "nt"):
        Home.ComputerName = os.getenv("COMPUTERNAME")
        Home.Username = os.getenv("USERNAME")
        Home.Homedir = os.getenv("HOMEPATH")
    else:
        Home.ComputerName = os.getenv()
        Home.Username = os.getenv("USER")
        Home.Homedir = os.getenv("HOME")
    return Home

def MainShellLoop():
    print ("--- Dash Shell ---")
    Home = InitInformation()
    userinput = None
    currentdir = Home.Homedir
    while (userinput != "exit"):
        rightnow = datetime.datetime.now()
        try:
            userinput = input(str(Home.ComputerName) + "\\" + str(Home.Username) + ":" + str(rightnow.month) + "/" + str(rightnow.day) + "/" + str(rightnow.year) + "@" + str(currentdir))
        except:
            print("Invalid Command specified, please try again")

MainShellLoop()
```

edit: Lol sorry guys forgot to say its supposed to run the input

Comment: I get a complaint about `os.getenv()` because it requires an argument.

Comment: @Indebi: And you're not even going to try to guess what you changed to make this happen?

Comment: This is one reason you should use source control, even for very small projects. Doesn't work? Just roll back to a version that does, and see what changed!

Comment: This is a nearly worthless question. The only good thing you did was post the full source. A better way of asking would include things such as "This is what I expected..." and "This is what I got instead.."

Comment: -1: I'm as baffled as you are.   And since you know what it used to do, you can fix the problem.  Since I have no hint as to what it's supposed to do, I can do nothing except shake my head and wonder how "I changed something that I no longer remember" can be allowed to happen.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was in a rush while posting this question

Comment: I'm closing this question and opening a new one, while rephrasing this one Sorry about this.

Comment: @indebi: "I was in a rush while posting this question".  If so, then fix the question.   "I changed something that I no longer remember" is still the funniest question I've seen in a long time.

Answer (score 2):

You should better describe your problem. Does it print the input prompt? Does it output anything? Does it exit or just sit there? I noticed a few issues while reading over this code that might help. You should be using raw_input(), not input(). Also, you don't actually do anything with userinput unless it == 'exit'. Which is won't, because you are just using input(), not raw_input(), so the person would have to enter 'exit' (including quotes) or else the loop will never exit. (Assuming it's not Python 3 Code)

Comment: If the code is Python 3 (which it may well be, since `print` is used as a function), then `input()` is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's doing nothing because there's no code to make it do anything. Try inserting a line like

```
print("You entered:", userinput)
```

at an appropriate place in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

`os.getenv()` must have at least one param. Try `os.getenv("HOST")` or something.

Comment: It worked without anything in it before, and its being coded on Windows 7 so that part isn't run yet